# Attempt to open h5py file, returns errorno = 17, error message = 'file exists'

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

> import numpy as np 
>   import h5py
>
> with h5py.File("testfile.hdf5", "w-") as f:
>       arr = np.ones((5,2))
>       f["my dataset"] = arr
>       dset = f["my dataset"]

This code runs correctly the first time, but when run a second time, returns the following error:

> %run "C:\Users\James\Google Drive\Python Scripts\Python and
>   HDF5\Chapter3.py"
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
>   last) C:\Users\James\Google Drive\Python Scripts\Python and
>   HDF5\Chapter3.py in ()
>         6 with h5py.File("testfile.hdf5") as f:
>         7     arr = np.ones((5,2))
>   ----> 8     f["my dataset"] = arr
>         9     dset = f["my dataset"]
>        10
>
> h5py_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
>   (C:\pisi\tmp\h5py-2.6.0-2\work\h5py-2.6.0\h5py_objects.c:2696)()
>
> h5py_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
>   (C:\pisi\tmp\h5py-2.6.0-2\work\h5py-2.6.0\h5py_objects.c:2654)()
>
> C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\h5py_hl\group.py
>   in **setitem**(self, name, obj)
>       291         else:
>       292             ds = self.create_dataset(None, data=obj, dtype=base.guess_dtype(obj))
>   --> 293             h5o.link(ds.id, self.id, name, lcpl=lcpl)
>       294 
>       295     @with_phil
>
> h5py_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
>   (C:\pisi\tmp\h5py-2.6.0-2\work\h5py-2.6.0\h5py_objects.c:2696)()
>
> h5py_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
>   (C:\pisi\tmp\h5py-2.6.0-2\work\h5py-2.6.0\h5py_objects.c:2654)()
>
> h5py\h5o.pyx in h5py.h5o.link
>   (C:\pisi\tmp\h5py-2.6.0-2\work\h5py-2.6.0\h5py\h5o.c:3610)()
>
> RuntimeError: Unable to create link (Name already exists)
>
> %run "C:\Users\James\Google Drive\Python Scripts\Python and
>   HDF5\Chapter3.py"
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call
>   last) C:\Users\James\Google Drive\Python Scripts\Python and
>   HDF5\Chapter3.py in ()
>         4 from timeit import timeit
>         5 
>   ----> 6 with h5py.File("testfile.hdf5", "w-") as f:
>         7     arr = np.ones((5,2))
>         8     f["my dataset"] = arr
>
> C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\h5py_hl\files.py
>   in **init**(self, name, mode, driver, libver, userblock_size, swmr,
>   **kwds)
>       270 
>       271                 fapl = make_fapl(driver, libver, **kwds)
>   --> 272                 fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, swmr=swmr)
>       273 
>       274                 if swmr_support:
>
> C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\h5py_hl\files.py
>   in make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr)
>        94         fid = h5f.open(name, h5f.ACC_RDWR, fapl=fapl)
>        95     elif mode in ['w-', 'x']:
>   ---> 96         fid = h5f.create(name, h5f.ACC_EXCL, fapl=fapl, fcpl=fcpl)
>        97     elif mode == 'w':
>        98         fid = h5f.create(name, h5f.ACC_TRUNC, fapl=fapl, fcpl=fcpl)
>
> h5py_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
>   (C:\pisi\tmp\h5py-2.6.0-2\work\h5py-2.6.0\h5py_objects.c:2696)()
>
> h5py_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
>   (C:\pisi\tmp\h5py-2.6.0-2\work\h5py-2.6.0\h5py_objects.c:2654)()
>
> h5py\h5f.pyx in h5py.h5f.create
>   (C:\pisi\tmp\h5py-2.6.0-2\work\h5py-2.6.0\h5py\h5f.c:2109)()
>
> IOError: Unable to create file (Unable to open file: name =
>   'testfile.hdf5', errno = 17, error message = 'file exists', flags =
>   15, o_flags = 502)

The code and error were run in Canopy // Python 3.5. I also ran it in Spyder and received the same result. I also tried using

> with h5py.File("testfile.hdf5", "a") as f:

with no success.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the exact same error message when I use [`HDF5Matrix`](https://keras.io/utils/#hdf5matrix) class in `keras`(v2.2.2). However, I failed to find a mature solution to completely avoid this error when I have multiple training processes which all need to access the same `HDF5` data on the disk. Only one process could successfully access this `HDF5` data, while all others would report the same error, even though I modified the reading mode from the default `r+` to `r`. I gave up and used the workable solution that keeps multiple copies of `HDF5` data and one copy for each training process.

Answer (score 1):

As per http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/file.html, the `w-` mode is designed to cause the open operation to fail if the file already exists.