# "File exists" error when trying to open .mat file in python with h5py library

Tags: python, matlab, h5py

I try to access part of the data (which is called "mask") in a .mat file using the following code:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

g = h5py.File('/Path/to/file.mat')
x = g["mask"]
print(np.array(x))
```

This seems to work pefectly fine for another .mat file but somehow for this one i keep getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 190, in make_fid
fid = h5f.open(name, h5f.ACC_RDWR, fapl=fapl)
File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 85, in h5py.h5f.open
OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 193, in make_fid
fid = h5f.open(name, h5f.ACC_RDONLY, fapl=fapl)
File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 85, in h5py.h5f.open
OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
g = h5py.File('maskH07.mat')
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 394, in __init__
swmr=swmr)
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 195, in make_fid
fid = h5f.create(name, h5f.ACC_EXCL, fapl=fapl, fcpl=fcpl)
File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 105, in h5py.h5f.create
OSError: Unable to create file (unable to open file: name = 'maskH07.mat', errno = 17, error message = 'File exists', flags = 15, o_flags = a02)
```

Would greatly appreciate any help

Comment: Are you sure the file is in the python working directory? Easy check with `print(os.listdir())` and `print(os.getcwd())`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to read the file you can use (File must exist)

```
g = h5py.File('/Path/to/file.mat', 'r')
```

if you want write to the file you can use (File must exist)

```
g = h5py.File('/Path/to/file.mat', 'w')
```

if you want both you can use (If file exist truncate it else create it)

```
g = h5py.File('/Path/to/file.mat', 'r+')
```

See [documentation](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/file.html) and [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230064/attempt-to-open-h5py-file-returns-errorno-17-error-message-file-exists)